# How to keep WiFi on during "Suspend"?

Tags: wireless, suspend

When searching, I saw a load of questions about WiFi not turning back on properly after coming out of suspend; WiFi is turned off when going into suspend.

However, I have some background tasks I need running that need to connect to the internet, even in suspend mode.

Is there a way I can keep the WiFi on when suspended?

(I'm plugged in to power 95% of the time, so I'm not bothered about it draining my battery.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible - suspend mode means the cpu is halted and the system uses only power to maintain the RAM's content.

Comment: Is this the same on Windows? Becuase I'm fairly sure some programs I'm running are accessing the internet when my Windows 'sleeps'. Oh well, perhaps I'm confusing things. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can however keep your laptop (I presume?) running, even if you have it closed. This would leave any tasks on your computer running (and of course the WiFi connected. For changing the behavior when closing the lid, go to settings -> power -> change "When lid is closed".

Comment: In Windows go into Device Manager, find your Wireless interface entry and go to the Power Management tab.   Unclick the power management checkbox